# Perl include continuation lines and ignore double quotes

Tags: perl, double, quotes, lines, continuation

I was working on a script that needs to produce *foo* for the first two lines and *bar* for the last three. There are two issues i am running into here.

1. How do I get Perl to ignore the double quotes around the first foo?
2. How do I get it recognize the backslash as a continuation line? -

Sample input:

```
reset -name "foo"
quasi_static -name foo
reset \
-name bar
set_case_analysis -name "bar"
```

My Code:

```
   if (/^\s*set_case_analysis.*\-name\s+(\S+)/) 
   {
      $set_case_analysis{$1}=1;
      print "Set Case $1\n";
   } 
   elsif (/^\s*quasi_static.*\-name\s+(\S+)/) 
   {
      $quasi_static{$1}=1;
      print "Quasi Static $1\n";
   } 
   elsif (/^\s*reset\s+.*\-name\s+(\S+)/) 
   {
      $reset{$1}=1;
      print "Reset $1\n";
    }
```

Comment: Are you reading this data in line-by-line from a file? Does the line continuation character always appear in the same place?

Comment: Yes, the data is being read line-by-line. The line continuation character does not always appear in the same column of text but when it appears, it is on the last space of the line. @ialarmedalien

Answer (score 0):

If you're going through a file line by line, you can keep partial lines in a variable and concatenate them with the next line. Read through the code - I have commented the functionality.

```
my $curr;
my $txt;
open ( IN, "<", 'yourinputfile.txt' ) or die 'Could not open file: ' . $!;
while (<IN>) {
  chomp;
  # if the line ends with a backslash, save the segment in $curr and go on to the next line
  if ( m!(.*?) \$! ) {
    $curr = $1;
    next;
  }
  # if $curr exists, add this line on to it
  if ( $curr ) {
    $curr .= $_;
  }
  # otherwise, set $curr to the line contents
  else {
    $curr = $_;
  }

  if ( $curr =~ /set_case_analysis -name\s+\"?(\S+)/) {
      # if the string is in quotes, the regex will leave the final " on the string
      # remove it
      ( $txt = $1 ) =~ s/"$//;
      print "Set Case $txt\n";
      $set_case_analysis{$txt}=1;
   }
   elsif ($curr =~ /quasi_static -name\s+(\S+)/) {
      ( $txt = $1 ) =~ s/"$//;
      print "Quasi Static $txt\n";
      $quasi_static{$txt}=1;

   }
   elsif ($curr =~ /reset .*?-name\s+\"?(\S+)/) {
      ( $txt = $1 ) =~ s/"$//;
      print "Reset $txt\n";
      $reset{$txt}=1;
  }
  # reset $curr
  $curr = '';
}
```

You could make it more compact and neat by doing something like this:

```
if ( $curr =~ /(\w+) -name \"?(\S+)/) {
      ( $txt = $2 ) =~ s/"$//;
      $data{$1}{$txt}=1;
}
```

You would get a nested hash structure with the three keys, `set_case_analysis`, `quasi_static`, and `reset`, and the various different values from `-name`.

```
%data = (
  quasi_static => ( foo => 1, bar => 1 ),
  reset => ( pip => 1, pap => 1, pop => 1 ),
  set_case_analysis => ( foo => 1, bar => 1 )
);
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to perl so I'm a bit lost with the regular expressions, however I am able to follow along.I keep getting errors that say 'requires specific package name'. Are there any packages that I need to import?

Comment: all the above is vanilla perl that should work without any special settings. Is there more code that might be causing the error? Can you post the full error message?

Comment: I am currently getting syntax errors around the brackets of my first section of code, posted above. Should I remove it since all it is doing is pushing values to variables? Is that not what your edits do?